# how to avoid code duplication with const and non-const member functions being input into templates

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, methods, constants

when attempting to get functions' signatures when they are input into templates its fairly easy, just do the following:

```
template <class OutType, class... ArgTypes>
void foo(OutType (*func)(ArgTypes...));
```

it is only marginally more complicated to get a non-static member function:

```
template <class OutType, class MemberOf, class... ArgTypes>
void foo(OutType (MemberOf::*func)(ArgTypes...));

// or

template <class OutType, class MemberOf, class... ArgTypes>
void foo(OutType (MemberOf::*func)(ArgTypes...) const);
```

but how exactly do you combine the two function declarations above into one when it doesn't matter whether or not the input method is const?

Comment: Depending on what you need `template<typename Func> void foo(Func func)` is my first goto.

Comment: @NathanOliver I need all the types in the signature available to me within the function unfortunately.

Comment: I agree with Nathan, using `std::invoke` you can support more than just function pointers

Comment: @MatthewL In that case what about `template <class OutType, class... ArgTypes>
void foo(std::function<OutType(ArgTypes...)>);`?

Comment: that seems like it would work, but `foo(std::function<[whole function signature]>(&bar::do))` feels needlessly verbose, especially with descriptive function/class names

Comment: In what situation exactly do you need all the types in the signature deduced immediately? Why can't you dispatch to a helper function?

Comment: Why is this a problem? Any decent linker will fold identical function bodies into one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the presence or absence of `const` on a non-static member function is not a feature that can be deduced separately from the function type it appertains to. Therefore, if you want to write a single `foo` template declaration that is limited to accepting pointers to members (but accepts both `const` and non-`const` member functions) then it would have to be:

```
template <class MemberOf, class F>
void foo(F MemberOf::*func);
```

For example:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class MemberOf, class F>
void foo(F MemberOf::*func) {
    static_assert(std::is_same<F, void(int) const>::value);
}

struct S {
    void bar(int) const {}
};

int main() {
    foo(&S::bar);
}
```

You cannot have `F`'s argument types deduced at that point. You would have to dispatch to a helper function. (But we cannot deduce all the types at once while also writing a single declaration that accepts both `const` and non-`const`. If that's the only thing you'll accept, then sorry, it's not possible.) We can do this like so:

```
template <class T>
struct remove_mf_const;

template <class R, class... Args>
struct remove_mf_const<R(Args...)> {
    using type = R(Args...);
};

template <class R, class... Args>
struct remove_mf_const<R(Args...) const> {
    using type = R(Args...);
};

template <bool is_const, class F, class OutType, class MemberOf, class... ArgTypes>
void foo_helper(F func, OutType (MemberOf::*)(ArgTypes...)) {
    // now you have all the types you need
}

template <class MemberOf, class F>
void foo(F MemberOf::*func) {
    static_assert(std::is_function<F>::value, "func must be a pointer to member function");
    using NonConstF = typename remove_mf_const<F>::type;
    constexpr bool is_const = !std::is_same<F, NonConstF>::value;
    foo_helper<is_const>(func, (NonConstF MemberOf::*)nullptr);
}
```

[Coliru link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a12b82b2caed899)